# How to get the selected value in each select in a form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with a lot of select.

Before to send the form, I need to check if all select have an option value.

I have it, but without success :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {

 $("#myForm select:selected").each(function(index){ 
   alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val()); 
 }); 

});
```

How do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
$("#myForm select").each(function(index){
    if ($(this).has('option:selected')){
        alert('Select number ' + index + ': ' + $(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it like this:

```
$("#myForm select:selected").each(function(index){
  alert(index + ': ' + $(this).val());
});
```

That will alert all selected values of the select's in your myForm.

Comment: show us your html code, because without seeing it, it is a bit difficult to determine the best selector !

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = $("select #myForm").filter(function(index){
                 return !$(this).val();
            }).length == 0;

alert(valid)
```